# Find the function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Find function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which has limit **only** at $0$ and $1$

I think function $f(x)=x(x-1)$ when $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=-x(x-1)$ when $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ satisfy conditions but I don't know how to prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of $f$ is fantastic. We just need to show that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ doesn't exist whenever $c \neq 0$ and $c \neq 1$. To this end, suppose that $c \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0, 1 \}$. Let $s_n$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $c$, and $t_n$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $c$. What can we conclude?

*Hint: Consider the convergence of $f(s_n)$, and $f(t_n)$*.

Comment: can we say that these sequances has different limits at every points ?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Recall that $f(x_n) \to x$ converges if and only if for every sub-sequence $x_{n_k}$, $f(x_{n_k}) \to x$. So, we just need to find two sub-sequences which produce different limit values to show that the whole limit does not exist. Plug in $s_n$, and $t_n$ into $f(x)$, and see what you get. Are they equal?

Comment: no since $f(s_n) \to c(c-1)$ and $f(t_n) \to -c(c-1)$ but for $c \notin \{0,1 \}$ we have $c(c-1) \neq -c(c-1)$ , correct ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

We have $$|f(x)|=|x(x-1)|\xrightarrow{x\to a}0=f(a)$$
where $a$ is  $0$ or $1$. Hence we proved that $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $1$. Now for $a\not\in\{0,1\}$ and using the sequential characterization of the limit we prove easily that $f$ hasn't a limit on $a$.